# How to make jackson automatically add href to javax.ws.rs resources?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

The code below will return json of the User. How can I make it also add href parameters to this resource and maybe hrefs of resources inside?

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getUsers() {
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    ArrayList<UserEntity> users = userDAO.getAll();
    return Response.ok(users).build();
  }
}
```

I have the following Application code:

```
@ApplicationPath("v1")
public class AppConfig extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        final Set<Object> instances = new HashSet<Object>();
        JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
        jacksonJsonProvider.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        instances.add(jacksonJsonProvider);
        return instances;
    }
}
```

I'm using Jersey for this

Comment: which framework are you using, Apache CXF, or Jersey?

Comment: You could take a look at [Jersey's Declarative Hyperlinking](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html). You will most likely be seeking a JAX-RS solution, I don't think Jackson will be able to provide what you are looking for on its own.